# Split large text file into multiple smaller ones using text analysis/regex

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, scripting

I have an annoying problem where I've been provided a file by a third party which is basically a huge set of classes (C# for reference). I've now had several revisions of this class now and for some unknown reason, the third party developers move classes around in the file from revision to revision. This makes dealing with any changes to their previous version problematic and time-consuming.

```
public class Abc
{
  ...
}

public class Xyz
{
  ...
}
```

As such, I'd like to be able to split out their delivered file into multiple files (named after their class, eg Abc.cs, Xyz.cs etc). I'll have a few more files but at least I'll be able to see any changes easily as I can just run the same script on a delivered file and can perform a diff on the generated files to determine any revisions to that particular class.

I have both experience with Powershell and Regex and I thought that this would be possible in PS, but honestly, my head is hitting a brick wall. In my somewhat lame attempts, I have managed to extract each closing class bracket (`}`) from the file, and nothing more. I also tried regexing everything between `"\r\npublic class "` and `"\r\n}"` (`\r\npublic class(.*)\r\n}\r\n`) but this either resulted in just the first class being output, the entire file being moved or just not working at all. This clearly shows that I'm not iterating over instances of `public class` but also that my examples closely resemble a solution that is more suited to splitting out a CSV rather than a multi-line solution.

It should be noted that, in all instances the `public class` declaration and closing bracket are on new lines, so there shouldn't be any edge cases where this would trip up. The file is not particularly large (<2MB) and reading it via `Get-Content` takes no times at all. My initial research suggested I use `StreamReader`, but that's unnecessary overkill for my use-case.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated here.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This is probably a job for [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split by `public class` at line start:

```
(Get-Content r:\1.cs | Out-String) -split '(?:^|\r\n)public class\s+' -ne '' | 
    ForEach {
        $className = $_ -replace '(?s)^(\w+).*$', '$1'
        "public class $_" | Out-File "r:\$className.cs" -encoding UTF8
    }
```

Tweaks:

In PS3.0+: use `(Get-Content r:\1.cs -raw)` instead of `(Get-Content r:\1.cs | Out-String)`
In any PS: `[IO.File]::ReadAllText('r:\1.cs')` is even faster.

Comment: Thank you for this! I had considered just splitting by `public class` but it missed off class attributes like `[Serialization]` on the previous line. However, I can handle that with what you've provided. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that I threw together that may work for you, assuming that you only want to extract public classes: https://regex101.com/r/urLWuz/2

```
(public\s*class\s*(\S*)\s*\{.*?(?:\}(?=\s*(?:(?:public\s*class)|$))))
```

- `(` - begin capture group containing the entire class

  - `public\s*class\s*(\S*)` - Match class declaration and capture name. `\s` will match any whitespace, `\S` will match any non-whitespace
  - `\s*\{` - Match beginning brace of the class's contents
  - `.*?` - lazy match of anything inside. If this is instead greedy it will match all the classes as one match.
  - `(?:\}(?=\s*(?:(?:public\s*class)|$)))` - match the brace that ends the class's contents using a non-capturing group

    - `\}(?=\s*(?:(?:public\s*class)|$))` - match the closing brace using a positive lookahead that asserts that what follows the closing brace is optional whitespace followed by either another class, or the end of the file. If don't account for the end of the file possibility then the last class will not be captured. The non-capturing groups are used for grouping with capturing.
- `)` - close the capturing group for the entire matched class

This should capture each class as well as the class name. Basically, it knows which brace is the closing brace for the class by checking for a class declaration following the brace, or the end of the file.

This will need to be modified slightly if all the classes are within a namespace.

Comment: Thanks for this! Ultimately I didn't use this but I was previously unaware of regex101.com which should help me no end as my current go-to regex tool - Regex Coach - isn't always that great!